# Is this tail recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, computer-science, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I have tried to find examples of tail recursion and I really don't see the difference between regular and tail. If this isn't tail recursion, can someone tell me why its not?

```
public static long fib(long index) {

// assume index >= 0

if (index == 0) // Base case

  return 0;

else

  if (index == 1) // Base case

    return 1;

  else

    // Reduction and recursive calls

    return fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);

}  // end of method fib(long index)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the method in the question does not use a tail recursion. A tail recursion is easily recognizable: the recursive step is the *last* thing that happens in the method.

In your code, *after* both recursive calls end, there's one more operation to do - an addition. So the method is *recursive*, but not *tail-recursive*.

For comparison purposes, here's a tail-recursive implementation of the `fib()` method - notice how we need to pass extra parameters to save the state of the recursion, and more importantly, notice that there are no operations left to do after the recursive call returns.

```
public static long fib(int n, long a, long b) {
    return n == 0 ? b : fib(n-1, a+b, a);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
fib(10, 1, 0) // calculates the fibonacci of n=10
=> 55
```

The previous implementation will work fine up to n=92, for bigger numbers you'll have to use `BigInteger` instead of `long`, and better switch to an iterative algorithm.

Comment: Your answer is great except for this line:  "So the method is recursive, but not tail-recursive."  As you implied at the beginning of your answer, tail-recursiveness is an attribute of the recursive call, not of the method.  You might choose to say a method is TR if all the call sites are TR, but that's a simplification that might confuse readers including the OP.

Comment: @Óscar López - I am unfamiliar with the part "?  b :" what does that do?

Comment: @BluceRee it's called a conditional expression. The same code is equivalent to `if (n == 0) return b; else return fib(n-1, a+b, a);`

Comment: @Gene I don't follow you :( it's not clear what part is not clear. Feel free to edit my answer, if you consider that it can be improved - I'll be thankful for that!

Comment: @Gene - I don't follow you either.  You say *"[a]s you implied at the beginning of your answer, tail-recursiveness is an attribute of the recursive call, not of the method"*.  But I don't see where he implies that.  And I don't even see what the distinction is.  It is the method and how it is written that determines whether the calls are tail recursive.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - One more question, sorry I am having a really hard time comprehending this concept. How would you get the fib of a different number than 10. I plugged 10 into my program like you did and it came out with 55. I plugged other numbers in and it did not seem correct. Do you have to change the 1 and the 0 as well? If so, what exactly do those numbers do. Recursion is very hard for me to understand. :(

Comment: @BluceRee Just change the first number. For example, to calculate fibonacci of 15, do this: `fib(15, 1, 0)`. I hope you're not trying to calculate the function for big numbers, fibonacci grows pretty fast and a `long` won't be able to hold the value

Answer (score 4):

@Óscar López has answered the Question.

The reason that people are interested in knowing whether a call is tail call is that there is an optimization that allows a tail call to be replaced with a branch, thereby avoiding the need to create a new stack frame.  This allows unbounded tail recursion on a bounded stack.

However, since you tagged the Question with `java`, you should know that current Java implementations DO NOT implement tail call optimization.  A deeply recursive method call in Java is liable to result in a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: I think IBM JDK/JRE (don't remember the name) used to optimize the tail-calls.

Comment: That is interesting.  I wonder how they managed to get around the security related problem that prevents them from implementing this in the Sun / Oracle / OpenJDK codebase ...